# .htaccess rewrites even if redirectmatch applies

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I migrated to a new domain name and now use .PHP instead of classic .ASP.
I successfully setup an .htaccess to redirect all the old .ASP requests to .PHP requests.  But just can't get the root default document to redirect.

This is an example of my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on    
RedirectMatch ^(.*).asp http://newdomain.com$1.php
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1
```

With .htaccess looking like the above (second line commented out), a request to

```
http://olddomain.com
```

simply shows the old domain.  But deep files work as I wish.  Eg. A request to

```
http://olddomain.com/somefile.asp
```

will go to

```
http://newdomain/somefile.php
```

If I uncomment the second line, the root now redirects correctly but everything else is messed up.  Eg. A request to

```
http://olddomain.com/somefile.asp
```

will simply rewrite to:

```
http://newdomain/somefile.asp
```

(instead of .php)

So I want line 1 to take priority and line 2 only should apply if they exactly request

```
http://olddomain.com
```

I investigated and discovered that maybe adding [L] at the end of line 1 was my answer.  However, when I do this I get 500 - Internal Server Error.

Any ideas?

Comment: anubhava, that worked great.  Thank you so much!  I have one more weird problem.  I have one page that doesn't redirect to .php.  It still tries to redirect to an .asp page.  Eg. http://olddomain.com/pages/events/events.asp still goes to http://newdomain.com/pages/events/events.asp  Meanwhile just about every other page I try works well. Eg. http://olddomain.com/pages/products/products.asp correctly goes to http://newdomain.com/pages/products/products.php    --- Maybe "event" is some sort of reserved word?  My .htaccess file is in the root & there is none in /pages or /pages/events directory

Comment: I retract that last statement, events.asp is redirecting fine now. Maybe my old regular expression was screwed up somehow though.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `RedirectMatch` i.e. `mod_alias` rules with `mod_rewrite` ones. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.asp$ http://newdomain.com/$1.php [L,NC,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```